# Installing cassandra in ubuntu?

Tags: cassandra

I have already installed cassandra in ubuntu using with [wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/DebianPackaging)

Problem is I have no control over which version to install and upgrade to in feature.

I am want to be able to install specific version not just latest, because i have a machine running 0.6.2 now i want a another node and i want to install 0.6.2.

How can i install debian package for specific version instead of latest one?

Comment: why dont you like 0.6.3?

Comment: i like 0.6.3, but i already have a node with 0.6.2 so i want another node with 0.6.2, don't want to update existing node right now

Answer (score 3):

for installing a specific version of cassandra you can do something like this:

in this case i want to install cassandra 1.2.8

> sudo apt-get clean
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install cassandra=1.2.8

Comment: i know you may resolve your problem but i answer it after 3 years for someone that don't know the answer and come here to see the answer

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do something like this, that I have found so far is [pinning](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto). This is a little inconvenient at the moment because you have to manually create the pinning preferences (and change them if necessary). Also, the pinning will not work with aptitude in case you use this.

Another example is the pinning I have done for php [here](https://edge.launchpad.net/~txwikinger/+archive/php5.2). However, you have to make sure that whatever version you want to have is available in the repos/ppas that you have configured in your sources.list (sources.list.d).